# Fortran implicit change type

Tags: fortran, implicit-conversion, implicit, fortran77

I'm reworking some old Fortran code (F77  i suppose), to be compiled with Intel compiler. I came across some SLATEC routines in this form:

```
subroutine cffti (n,wsave)

     dimension wsave(1)

     iw1 = n+n+1
     iw2 = iw1+n+n
     call cffti1 (n,wsave(iw1),wsave(iw2))

     return
  end subroutine cffti


 subroutine cffti1 (n,wa,ifac)

     ....
     ....
 end subroutine cffti
```

Wsave is an array, whose first part is supposed to store floats while the second (from iw2) to store integers.

All the variables are implicit so when wsave(iw2) is passed to ifac is interpreted as an integer and the value in ifac has no sense.

I'm getting confuse: how could all this stuff work correctly?
How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This sort of conversion to fill the data correctly can be done using `EQUIVALENCE` in Fortran 77. Fortran 95 offers `TRANSFER` for the same purpose.

```
wsave(iw2:) = transfer(some_integer_array, wsave)
```

Receiving the data is not a problem because of the implicit interface which passes just pointers and does not check types. If you need the inner part to use explicit interface, you could use the same also inside.

In modern code just use 2 different arrays with different types and stay away from these techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating a bit on VF's answer -- quite likely cffti1 uses that integer array as scratch space, so that the values are never accessed anywhere else. ie. you might not find (or need) equivalence or transfer statements.   The documentation for the highest level subroutine probably says something like "wsave should be declared 4n+1 with the result you want returned in the first 2n values".

In that case to 'modernize' the code you *could* do away with the ifac argument and allocate the scratch space it inside the subroutine.  I would be reluctant to make such changes without really studying the code in detail though.

That said, what "problem" are you having?  You may just need to turn off some overly aggressive type checking.

---

edit, found docs here http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~marp/slatec/routin-j.htm

```
 WSAVE   a work array which must be dimensioned at least 4*N+15...
```

"work array " ->> "scratch space" --> don't concern yourself with the contents..